# A question on positive semi definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, generalized-inverse

Suppose $A,B$ are symmetric, positive semi-definite matrices of same order such that $A \preceq B \preceq \kappa A$. How to prove that this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\kappa}A^+ \preceq B^+ \preceq A^+$? Here $A^+$ is the generalized inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^+$ is in particular the Moore Penrose inverse, then we can proceed as follows: There exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$
\tilde A = U^TAU = \pmatrix{A_0 & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
where $A_0$ is invertible (i.e. strictly positive definite).
We now have
$$
A \preceq B \preceq \kappa A \implies\\
\tilde A \preceq \tilde B \preceq \kappa \tilde A \implies\\
U^TAU \preceq U^TBU \preceq \kappa U^TAU \implies\\
\pmatrix{A_0 & 0\\0 & 0} \preceq \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & B_{22}} \preceq \kappa \pmatrix{A_0 & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
Now, from the right-side inequality, we have
$$
\pmatrix{A_0 & 0\\0 & 0} - \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & B_{22}} = 
\pmatrix{A_0 - \kappa B_{11} & -B_{12}\\ -B_{21} & -B_{22}} \succeq 0 \tag{RHS}
$$
and from the left-side inequality, we have
$$
\pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & B_{22}} - \pmatrix{A_0 & 0\\0 & 0} = \pmatrix{B_{11} - A_0 & B_{12}\\ B_{21} & B_{22}} \succeq 0
\tag{LHS}
$$
Now, since any principal submatrix of a positive semidefinite matrix is also positive semidefinite, we have $B_{22} \succeq 0$ and $-B_{22} \succeq 0$, which must mean that $B_{22} = 0$.  Since $\tilde B$ is positive semidefinite, we have
$$
\pmatrix{x^T & y^T} \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & 0}\pmatrix{x\\y} \geq 0 \implies\\
x^TBx - 2x^TB_{12}y \geq 0
$$
Noting that the above must hold for **all** choices of $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, conclude that $x^TB_{12} = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, which is to say that $B_{12} = B_{21}^T = 0$.  Thus, we have
$$
\tilde B = U^TBU = \pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
Now, it suffices to show that $\tilde A^+ \preceq \tilde B^+ \preceq \kappa \tilde A^+$.  To that effect, note that
$$
A_0 \preceq B_{11} \preceq \kappa A_0
$$
is an inequality of strictly positive definite matrices.  Thus, we have
$$
A_0^{-1} \succeq B_{11}^{-1} \succeq (\kappa A_0)^{-1} = \frac 1 \kappa A_0^{-1}
$$
Finally, we have
$$
\frac 1{\kappa}\tilde A^+  = \pmatrix{\frac 1 \kappa A_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0}
\preceq 
\tilde B^+ = \pmatrix{B_{11}^{-1} & 0\\0 &0} \preceq
\tilde A^+ = \pmatrix{A_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
Thus, we can reach the desired conclusion.  In particular:
$$
\frac 1{\kappa} A^+ = 
U[\frac 1{\kappa}\tilde A^+]U^T
 \preceq
\tilde B^+ = UB^+U^T \preceq
A^+ = U\tilde A^+ U^T
$$

---

Regarding the comment:

> Lemma: if $A \preceq B$ are positive definite matrices, then $A^{-1} \succeq B^{-1}$

Proof: Note that
$$
A \preceq B \implies\\
B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} \preceq I \implies\\
\text{all eigenvalues of } B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} \text{ are less than } 1 \implies\\
\text{all eigenvalues of } [B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}]^{-1} \text{ are more than } 1 \implies\\
B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2} \succeq I \implies\\
A^{-1} \succeq B^{-1}
$$

Comment: How is it true  positive definite matrices?

Comment: @SudiptaRoy I don't understand your comment

Comment: You have used the fact for strictly positive definite matrices at the end of your answer. ("is an inequality ....")

Comment: Now I get it.  See my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How can thsi be extendend if we are not using Moore Penrose generalized inverse?

Comment: @Manuel I suspect that this doesn't hold for all generalize inverses.  I had assumed that the original asker was talking about the Moore Penrose inverse specifically

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Do you Think this result can be extended to $ 0 \leq A \leq B \implies B^{+} \geq A^{+}$ withthe m oore Penrose inverse? In this case $A_0$ and $B_{11}$ are not necessarly the same size.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, that result holds.  The proof is a bit different, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you might be interested in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950304/does-0-leq-a-leq-b-implies-0-leq-b-dagger-leq-a-dagger/2950339#2950339

Answer (score 0):

Using Schur complement:

$$A\leq B\Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc}A&I\\I&B^{-1}\end{array}\right]\leq 0\Leftrightarrow B^{-1}-A^{-1}\leq0 \Leftrightarrow B^{-1}\leq A^{-1}$$

$$B\leq \kappa A\Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc}B&I\\I&\frac{1}{\kappa}A^{-1}\end{array}\right]\leq 0\Leftrightarrow  \frac{1}{\kappa} A^{-1}-B^{-1}\leq0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\kappa} A^{-1}\leq B^{-1}$$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not supposed to be nonsingular in this question.