# Does $ 0 \leq A \leq B \implies 0\leq B^\dagger \leq A^\dagger$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, generalized-inverse

The question is stated in the title. Where $A$ and $B$ are positive definite real matrices and $\dagger$ stands for the Moore Penrose inverse.

This question [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523595/a-question-on-positive-semi-definite-matrices) seems to be close but it has an aditional assumption that $Ker(A) = Ker(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work without the assumption on the null spaces. To see this, take $A=0$, $B\ge0$ but not zero. Then $A^\dagger\le B^\dagger$ but these matrices are not equal, thus the claim is not valid.